# Ext.net gridview columns getting distorted in IE 8

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, ext.net

i'm generating EXT.NET gridview dynamically as below,

```
public GridPanel GetGridView()
    {
        return new GridPanel
        {
            Border = false,
            ID = "grd",
            Cls = "x-grid-custom",
            StyleSpec = "margin-top:7px; margin-left:-2px",
            Scroll = ScrollMode.Both,
            OverflowX = Overflow.Auto,
            EnableColumnHide = false,
            ColumnLines = true,
            ForceFit = false,
          //Width = 1100,
            EmptyText = "No rows to display",
            Store = { this.CreateTabularStore() },
            ColumnModel =
            {
                Columns = {
                             new DateColumn {ID="ED", Text = "Effective Date",Wrap = true,DataIndex = "ED",Format="dd MMM yyyy",Groupable = true, Html="<i class='prfl_unfilter_icon' onclick='return ShowGridFilter(this);'></i>" ,Width = 110},
                            new Column {ID="PRICE", Text = "Price",DataIndex = "PRICE",Groupable = true, Html="<i class='prfl_unfilter_icon' onclick='return ShowGridFilter(this);'></i>" ,Width = 70},
                            new Column {ID="CURRENCY", Text = "Currency",DataIndex = "CURRENCY",Groupable = true, Html="<i class='prfl_unfilter_icon' onclick='return ShowGridFilter(this);'></i>" ,Width = 80},
                            new Column {ID="OFFICIAL",Text = "Official Price",DataIndex = "OFFICIAL",Groupable = true, Html="<i class='prfl_unfilter_icon' onclick='return ShowGridFilter(this);'></i>" ,Width = 100},
                            new DateColumn {ID="MARKETED_EFFECTIVE_DATE", Text = "Marketed Effective Date",DataIndex = "MARKETED_EFFECTIVE_DATE",Format="dd MMM yyyy",Groupable = true, Html="<i class='prfl_unfilter_icon' onclick='return ShowGridFilter(this);'></i>" ,Width = 100},
                            new Column {ID="MARKETING_DESC", Text = "Marketed",DataIndex = "MARKETING_DESC",Groupable = true, Html="<i class='prfl_unfilter_icon' onclick='return ShowGridFilter(this);'></i>" ,Width = 80},
                            new DateColumn {ID="DISCONTINUED_TS", Text = "Date Discontinued",DataIndex = "DISCONTINUED_TS",Format="dd MMM yyyy",Groupable = true, Html="<i class='prfl_unfilter_icon' onclick='return ShowGridFilter(this);'></i>" ,Width = 100},
                    }
            },
            Features = {
                           new Grouping(){HideGroupedHeader=false }
                           },
            View = { new Ext.Net.GridView() { LoadMask = true, LoadingText = "Loading..." } }
        };
    }
```

below is how i defined store in a method named `CreateTabularStore()`:

Store store;
        Model model;

```
store = new Store();
store.ID = "StorePD";
model = new Model();
model.Fields.AddRange(new ModelField[] {
                                                new ModelField("ED",ModelFieldType.Date),
                                                new ModelField("PRICE", ModelFieldType.Float),
                                                new ModelField("CURRENCY"),
                                                new ModelField("OFFICIAL"),
                                                new ModelField("MARKETED_EFFECTIVE_DATE",ModelFieldType.Date),
                                                new ModelField("MARKETING_STATUS_DESC"),
                                                new ModelField("DISCONTINUED_TS",ModelFieldType.Date)
                                                }
                    );
```

when i filter grid with `DateColumn` filter, grid columns are rendering distorted in **IE 8** Browser as shown in the image below

[image]

Comment: I have no idea. If you can provide a standalone runnable test case, I could investigate.

Comment: I ran the code and there was no problem, however the filter icon wasn't in the column header, how did you add it? i suspect that's the cause of the issue

Comment: also how do i set `Layout` to `Fit` of the dyanacally generated grid like above?